# Monthly Sales Volume Estimates Based on Annual Growth Rate

Tags: definite-integrals, exponential-function

Thanks for your help. I haven't taken a math class since Highschool, so hopefully this question makes sense.

I know the prior year's sales (units sold) were 7,387, and that unit sales are forecasted to grow at an annual rate of 9.2% for the foreseeable future. So looking forward:

$s = 7387*(1.092)^n$

where s = estimated units sold and n = number of years.

**How do I convert this to a *monthly* formula?** In other words, **How do I know how many sales will happen each month?**

I know that next years sales are estimated to be 8,067, and that the average monthly sales will be about 670, but how do I know the exact number each month? I barely remember integrals, but from what I remember, I thought the way to do it was:

$ \int_a^b \frac{7387(1.092)^x}{ln(1.092)} dx $

Where a and b are the start and end of the period I want to forecast. However, if I plug in $a=0$ and $b=1$ to see if it works on the annual sales, I get a value of $ \approx 7722 $ instead of $8067$.

What am I missing? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No calculus required.  In $12$ months you multiply by $1.092$, so the monthly multiplier $m$ must be such that $m^{12}=1.092, m=\sqrt[12]{1.092}\approx 1.0074$

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! How do I get the principle value? Given the growth rate, monthly sales is x*(1.0074)^n, but what is x? The previous annual sales are 7,387, so multiplying based on that doesn't give me the forecasted units sold in January.

Comment: It is this month's sales.  You should derive that from the $7387$ number by summing the geometric series to get the sales in the first and last months of the year, then growing to this month.

Comment: Okay, I was hoping there would be a calculus shortcut. Thank you so much!